# Which tables are used for getting orchestration information in OIM?

Tags: sql, oracle, oim

I want to track the orchestration of the user and validate its status, I wanted to know which tables are used for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`orchprocess` and `orchevents` are the two tables which can be used for checking orchestration details

Answer (score 0):

Sample Code to print the complete orchestration values at runtime.

String LASTNAME = retrieveUserInfo(orch, "Last Name");

private String retrieveUserInfo(Orchestration orch, String attributeName) {

```
    HashMap<String,Serializable> userAttributes = orch.getParameters();
    String attributeValue = (String) userAttributes.get(attributeName);
    
    System.out.println("Complete orch date ==> "+userAttributes.entrySet());
    
    return attributeValue;
}
```